# How to send a POST in python. 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, json, post, oauth-2.0

I am trying to use the iNaturalist API (https://www.inaturalist.org/pages/api+reference#auth) to upload some observations of algae. I am using python to try and create the POST requests, but I am getting the error "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'" when I try and complete the 2 step authentication with oauth2 to get my access token.

Here is what my code looks like so far:

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import dicttoxml

site = "https://www.inaturalist.org"
access_token_url = "https://www.inaturalist.org/oauth/token"
consumer_key = 'removed for security'
consumer_secret = 'removed for security'

oauth_verifier = 'removed for security'


params = {
    'client_id': consumer_key,
    'client_secret': consumer_secret,
    'code': oauth_verifier,
    'redirect_uri': 'http://www.example.com/',
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code'}

consumer = oauth.Consumer(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
client = oauth.Client(consumer)
resp, content = client.request(access_token_url, "POST",  body=params)
#resp, content = client.request("https://www.inaturalist.org/observations/890489", "GET")

print resp
print content
```

Comment: try putting ur params as a `list`. This is mostly because the API excepts lists and not dictionaries and dicts do not have a `split()` method but lists do

Comment: lists do not have a `split()` method either.

Comment: The `body` keyword expects a string. If you wanted to encode your dictionary as a JSON string, you could use the json module: `import json; json.dumps(params)`